# Reorder items in SliverList in Flutter with Drag & Drop

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I´m using a **SliverList** with **SliverChildBuilderDelegate** to generate the list items on the fly. Now I´m trying to allow the **user to reorder the list items via drag and drop** over a handle-icon on each item in a row.

I´ve tried different things (like Draggable Widget) but I haven´t found a solution so far. Has anyone already used drag & drop reordering with a SliverList Widget and can give me a hint?

Using ReorderableListView Widget is not possible, cause mixing a ListView to a SliverList. And I want to use the SliverAppBar to allow a fade-out-on-scroll effect as you can see here: https://medium.com/flutter-io/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f

**Here´s the structure of my SliverList:**

```
return Scaffold(
  body: RefreshIndicator(
    ...
    child: CustomScrollView(
      ...
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(...),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(...),
        )
        ...
```

Thanks in advance & best,
Michael

Answer (score 4):

Check out this [reorderables](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reorderables) package on pub. It recently added support to SliverList.

Screenshot here: [ReorderableSliverList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ZAM.gif)

The example has sliver list and app bar and shows what you are looking for. Just replace SliverList and SliverChildBuilderDelegate in your code with the counter parts from the package.

```dart
class _SliverExampleState extends State<SliverExample> {
  List<Widget> _rows;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _rows = List<Widget>.generate(50,
        (int index) => Text('This is sliver child $index', textScaleFactor: 2)
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
      setState(() {
        Widget row = _rows.removeAt(oldIndex);
        _rows.insert(newIndex, row);
      });
    }
    ScrollController _scrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context) ?? ScrollController();

    return CustomScrollView(
      // a ScrollController must be included in CustomScrollView, otherwise
      // ReorderableSliverList wouldn't work
      controller: _scrollController,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 210.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text('ReorderableSliverList'),
            background: Image.network(
              'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Yushan'
                '_main_east_peak%2BHuang_Chung_Yu%E9%BB%83%E4%B8%AD%E4%BD%91%2B'
                '9030.png/640px-Yushan_main_east_peak%2BHuang_Chung_Yu%E9%BB%83'
                '%E4%B8%AD%E4%BD%91%2B9030.png'),
          ),
        ),
        ReorderableSliverList(
          delegate: ReorderableSliverChildListDelegate(_rows),
          // or use ReorderableSliverChildBuilderDelegate if needed
//          delegate: ReorderableSliverChildBuilderDelegate(
//            (BuildContext context, int index) => _rows[index],
//            childCount: _rows.length
//          ),
          onReorder: _onReorder,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have some modifiable elements that I display with ReorderableSliverChildListDelegate. It's working fine, but I when I try to order it doesn't update the order in the list. This list is not dynamic BTW and I need to update elements inside the different categories

Answer (score 2):

There is now `SliverReorderableList` which you can use from the official Flutter widget library

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [flutter_reorderable_list](https://github.com/knopp/flutter_reorderable_list).  I've not yet tried it and am currently in the process of rolling my own, but it looks decent and [the example](https://github.com/knopp/flutter_reorderable_list/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) uses a CustomScrollView with SliverList.